# Strange answer from StringReplace

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement, string-manipulation, language-design

I have a list of strings and I would check if there is an empty string element, that's "", because I need to replace it with a "0". I try the following

```
StringReplace[{"90", "", "20"}, "" -> "0"]
```

and I get the following (unexpected) answer:

```
(* {"09000", "0", "02000"} *)
```

I think it is quite strange, not sure if it's a wrong or designed behavior. Any sensible explanation? 
It could be related to this other strange result:

```
StringPosition[{"90", "", "20"}, ""]

{{{1, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}}, {{1, 0}}, {{1, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}}}
```

I don't need a solution, because the alternative to my original issue is easy, but I'm posting here just to have other opinions.

Answer (score 8):

As others have indicated this result is not surprising at all. What you actually need is not `StringReplace` but `ReplaceAll` (`/.`):

```
{"90", "", "20"} /. "" -> "0"
```

> {"90", "0", "20"}

Comment: That's right! I was working with strings for other issues so my brain was focused on strings but actually here I do not need to check something "inside" a string, rather to check the whole object and ReplaceAll does the work. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

The illustrated behavior seems reasonable to me, even if it may not seem "natural."

1. For position or replacement a given pattern should match when it appears between any two sequences of characters, or it is at the beginning and end of a string.  A zero-length string effectively *is* between *every* pair of characters.  Why should it not match?  To keep it from matching would seem to call for an exception.  What other behavior would it have?
2. If a null string did not behave as shown how would you achieve this behavior?  I believe you would need another token such as [`WordBoundary`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WordBoundary.html).  It is shorter and equally logical for `""` to be used instead.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Taking a deeper look at the results and thanks to your explanation, now I can understand that the answers from both functions are correct and they do exactly what you well explained. Thanks for that explanation.

Answer (score 5):

That is a rather slippery replacement, "Find nothing and replace it with something" Try telling the replacement that there nothing between the beginning and end

```
StringReplace[{"90", "", "20"}, {StartOfString ~~ "" ~~ EndOfString -> "0"}]
```

Comment: You don't even need "", nor braces: StringReplace[{"90", "", "20"}, StartOfString ~~ EndOfString -> "0"]

Comment: As I commented above, in my actual case the most appropriate solution is ReplaceAll, however your solution with StartOfString/EndOfString is valid as well, in particular when one have to work inside strings with zero-length string. Thanks for that solution.

Answer (score 1):

`StringReplace` just searched from left to right and replaced all the zero-length string for once. Here is a way to visualize the process:

```
i = 0; StringReplace[{"90", "", "20"}, 
 "" :> ToString[Style["0", {Orange, 15 + 5 i++}], StandardForm]]
```

[image]

The inserted zero is dyed into orange and becomes bigger every time the replacing rule is applied so you can see where and how the replacement happens.

Comment: Yes, that's an example of what Mr.Wizard explained by words. Thanks for the answer.