# StringReplace with Style will cause another character in the string

Tags: replacement, string-manipulation

`StringReplace["abbaabbaa", "ab" -> "X"]` will output `XbaXbaa`, but `StringReplace["abbaabbaa", "ab" -> Style["X", Red]]` outputs

[image]

It is weird, as why there are horizontal lines between the replaced characters and other characters?

Comment: `Row@(List @@ StringReplace["abbaabbaa", "ab" -> Style["X", Red]])` ? Do a `//FullForm` at the end of an expression to see its internal structure.

Comment: @Syed Your ways works well. May you know the reason?

Comment: @xzczd `ToString` can solve this problem. It is a little difficult to understand it.

Comment: Not difficult at all. It's all because `Style["X", Red]` is no longer a `String`.

Comment: @xzczd So, what is it?

Comment: So you need to use `ToString` to convert it to a `String`. You may argue the output is confusing and need to be improved, though.

Comment: BTW, which version of Mathematica are you using? At least in the newest version, the `~~` is displayed, not `--`.

Comment: @xzczd 13.3.1 and this is the newest version. Sometimes `~~`, sometimes `--`. Very weird.

Answer (score 5):

Cannot find an exact duplicate at the moment, but the solution is mentioned at least in the following 3 posts:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/77842/1871

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/213639/1871

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/246756/1871

```
StringReplace["abbaabbaa", "ab" -> ToString[Style["X", Red], StandardForm]]
```

[image]

Comment: I was using `StandardForm` like `ToString[StringReplace["abbaabbaa", 
  "ab" -> Style["X", Red]], StandardForm]` before resorting to the embarassing workaround I posted.